# Подать сигнал в LPT кабель для замыкания реле. С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В общем, получил такое задание:
Создать программу, которая подает сигнал в LPT кабель для замыкания реле.

Был бы весьма признателен за советы в стиле "обрати внимание на...", "обратись туда-то или к тому-то", "я бы начал с ..." и в т.д.

P.S. Не кидайте готовый код или что-то в этом роде(разве что шаблон какой), в связи с тем что хочу понять что и как а не в тупую скатать.

Comment: Сам по себе язык C++ ничего не умеет делать. Разработчики для устройств пишут для него всевозможные сторонние библиотеки устройств которые потом подключаются в с++ проект. Эти библиотеки зачастую написаны на ассемблере. Вы тоже можете писать асм-вставками благо язык позволяет это сделать. Так что вам надо смотреть в сторону ассемблера и включения этого кода в свой проект.

Comment: Нужно искать в документации на WinAPI как работать с LPT-портом. Это вопрос операционной системы (предоставляемого ею интерфейса к оборудованию) а не языка программирования. Ещё такие вещи могут быть в библиотеках (boost, Qt и т.п.).

Comment: я бы начал с http://www.realcoding.net/article/view/2416 и обратил внимание на это http://logix4u.net/parallel-port/15-a-tutorial-on-parallel-port-interfacing

Comment: Формат SO не подразумевает сбор *мнений* и *советов* кто бы с чего начал. Советы вида "подучите ассемблер", "поищите в какой-нибудь библиотеке", которые вы насобираете, бесполезны для будущих посетителей. Например, у меня есть [готовый пример на C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/441815/Parallel-Port-Control-with-Csharp-NET). Так что моим советом было бы "подучите C#, из него точно можно работат с LPT!". Что, очевидно, совсем не принесло бы вам пользы.